# Массив объектов класса в C#

Tags: c#

Нужно данные из массива

```
Student[] students = new Student[3];
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                new Student("Amir", 320, new int[] { 4, 5, 4, 3 });
                new Student("Marsel", 320, new int[] { 4, 4, 4, 5 });
                new Student("Tolyan", 320, new int[] { 4, 5, 5, 5 });
```

перенести в эту часть

```
students[i] = new Student(name, number, Marks);
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Students
{
    struct Student : IComparer<Student>
    {
        public string student_name;
        public int group_number;
        public int[] Marks;
        public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
        {
            if (x.group_number > y.group_number)
                return 1;
            else if (x.group_number < y.group_number)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        public Student(string student_name, int group_number, int[] Marks)
        {
            this.student_name = student_name;
            this.group_number = group_number;
            this.Marks = Marks;
        }

        public double MediumBall()
        {
            double MedBall = 0;

            foreach (int i in Marks)
            {
                MedBall += i;
            }
            MedBall /= Marks.Length;

            return MedBall;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("ФИО: {0} \nНомер группы: {1}", student_name, group_number);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Student[] students = new Student[3];
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                new Student("Amir", 320, new int[] { 4, 5, 4, 3 });
                new Student("Marsel", 320, new int[] { 4, 4, 4, 5 });
                new Student("Tolyan", 320, new int[] { 4, 5, 5, 5 });
                string[] marks = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                 Console.Write("\n");

                int[] Marks = new int[5];
                for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
                    Marks[a] = int.Parse(marks[a].ToString());
                students[i] = new Student(name, number, Marks);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\n\nУпорядоченный по номеру группы массив студентов: ");
            Array.Sort(students, new Student());

            foreach (Student p in students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + p);
            }


            int count = 0;
            foreach (Student mark in students)
                if (mark.MediumBall() > 4)
                {
                    count++;
                }


            if (count == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("\nCтуденты со средним баллом больше 4 отсутствуют.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nСписок студентов со средним баллом больше 4: ");

            foreach (Student student in students)
                if (student.MediumBall() >= 4)
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + student.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. перенести в переменные

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
string name;
int number;
string[] marks = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

int[] Marks = new int[5];
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
Marks[a] = int.Parse(marks[a].ToString());

students[i] = new Student(name, number, Marks);
}

Comment: Если Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос своими силами, то оформляйте его как ответ, чтобы остальным тоже было видно решение сразу.